# Passing values to popup window by post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

i am trying to figure out how to pass an element id to a popup window that executes only php code. when the link is clicked, it grabs the link id, the opens the popup, how do i get the id to be passed?

**JS:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.char_inventory', function (e) {
    c = true;
    var id = e.currentTarget.id;
    //alert(id);
    if (id == "close_inventory") {
        $("#console").html("<div id=\"placeholder\"></div>");
        c = false;
    } else {
        /* $.post('input_commands/inventory_show.php',{id:id}, function(data) {
                text=data;
                elem = $("#console");
                //delay=100;
                elem.html(text);

            }); */
        function popUp(target, id) {
            //var id = parent.document.getElementById('id').value;
            popWin = window.open(target, "windowName", "width=400,height=250,status=yes");
        }
        popUp("input_commands/inventory_show.php", id);
    }
    load();

    //setTimeout(function(){c=false;},4000);
});
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to get the element ID? Or do you know how to get it but don't know how to pass it to the popup function?

Comment: i just dont know how to pass it to the pop up window. i get the id when clicking the link and it uses the currentTarget function to get it

Comment: Can you provide some html code, please. You trying to get id of clicked element, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean like:

```
function popUp(target, id) {
  window.some_id = id;
  window.open(target, "windowName", "width=400,height=250,status=yes");
}
```

and in child window:

```
//get some_id
var id = window.opener.some_id;
```

if you want to access the element with id from child window, do:

```
var id = window.opener.some_id;
var clickedElement = window.opener.$("#" +id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the line `popUp("input_commands/inventory_show.php", id);` to `popUp("input_commands/inventory_show.php?id="+id);` and on the page **inventory_show.php** you can use `$_REQUEST['id']` or `$_GET['id']` to get the value.

if you want to pass more parameters you can do :

```
popUp("input_commands/inventory_show.php?id="+id+"&param1="+param1_value+"&param2="+param2_value);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a very good educational issue: you will understand that the "narrative" or the "story" of the program execution *breaks* when you pass anyting to the server (PHP in this case).

Interpret the situation as two *separate* action:

1. User selects an item, the data is fowarded to server side for further processing.
2. When the server completes a processing, it sends the data to the client for displaying it.

In JavaScript, there is no single-line of program execution. There are *listeners*, and when an *event* occurs, like user action or timeout or arrival of an AJAX response, the appropiate *handler* executes and processes it (and may do things which will be generate further events in the future, e.g. set up a timer or initiate AJAX).

When you initiate something, which will cause event in the future, it's your responsibility that the event should contain all the information for the handler. Most of cases there is a simple way to do it: you can set up separate handler for each event, other cases you should use a mechanism to put ID or "target address" into the event, which the handler can recognise.